# unhandled exception c# dll

Tags: c#, dll, nullreferenceexception

I tring to test a new dll that I've build for c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String [] first = UserQuery.Get_All_Users();
            //MessageBox.Show(first);
        }
```

but I get the following error at `String [] first = UserQuery.Get_All_Users();`

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in User_Query.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I been tring to figure this one out for hours but can't find any null varibles

I post my dll in case the dll is wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace User_Query
{
    public class UserQuery
    {
        public static string[] Get_All_Users()
        {
            string[] names = new string[10];

            var path = string.Format("WinNT://{0},computer", Environment.MachineName);

            using (var computerEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path))
            {
                var userNames = from DirectoryEntry childEntry in computerEntry.Children
                                where childEntry.SchemaClassName == "User"
                                select childEntry.Name;
                byte i = 0;
                foreach (var name in userNames)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                    names[i] = name;
                    i++;
                }
                return names;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing exactly where the exception occurs - but it would help readability if you'd follow .NET naming conventions, and get rid of those underscores. (You should also consider using a `List<string>` instead of a string array.)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't set a break point in your dll and step through that?

Comment: Hate to look like a noob but I am new to this just googled .Net naming conventions never heard of this in uni.

Comment: @Brandon it doesn't seem to entry the dll if I put a break point and hint F11 it does not go into the dll code, I also do not see an option to add to process for the dll

Comment: @everyone can't post answer now but the reason it was not going into the dll was becasue I did not clean the project after assigning the dll build the to a new location even thought i changed the referance point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here turned out not to be the code but be VS2010 not loading the dll. This happen because I decided to  change the program from using the dll from the debug to the release version but I did not clean the project after doing it and therefore the program was not correctly loading the dll. All that need to be done was clean the project

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your. path variable... since there should be `\\` instead of `//`